Plotting theoretical efficient frontier over sample of risk/return data
I have a data set of a few thousand mutual funds that I wish to plot the annualized risk and three-year returns of and color code each dot by its sharpe ratio. Some degree of inefficiency is expected, not all data points themselves won't conform to the efficient frontier curve aka Markowitz bullet, but most should.
What is the appropriate formula for plotting a theoretical efficient frontier line, to superimpose atop my empirical data?
I am aiming to reproduce the chart below, but am not sure how to code the red dashed line. For the inefficient portfolios/funds I wish to make those dots gray or nearly invisible via by lowering their opacity.


Hi, would you mind sharing a bit more information about your optimization problem? I will help us to give you a hint about the red line, thanks

Maybe another way to phrase the question would be, given an existing data set, how can we construct the theoretical efficient frontier as a line that python graphing libraries can understand, especially if using native python data structures

In principle the equation of the efficient frontier is a well known function of the var covar matrix $\Sigma$. See for ex. equation (20) here https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2022/01/09/geometry-efficient-frontier/ .Working with a 2000 x 2000 matrix could be challenging however, it may fail to be invertible for example, due to numerical issues. There are also techniques to deal with this. Or you could use a sample of fewer MFs.
